# Cannot understand or convert Microsoft Graph API HTTP request to python request

Tags: python, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api

HTTP request mentioned in Microsoft Graph API's documentation found at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getmailboxusagedetail?view=graph-rest-beta)

```
GET /reports/getMailboxUsageDetail(period='{period_value}')
```

I cannot understand how to incorporate the data mentioned within the round parenthesis

```
(period='{period_value}')
```

I tried adding this to query parameters, but it didn't work.

```
URL="https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getMailboxUsageDetail"
    
queryParams={"period":"D7"}
requests.get(URI, params=queryParams)
```

But, it didn't work.

Comment: Where is the header?

Comment: it's just a sample. i added proper auth headers in my original request. i am able to get data for other requests, just not this one.

Comment: So you code looks like requests.get(URI,headers=headers params=queryParams)? what is the respond code you get?

Comment: "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'getMailboxUsageDetail'.",

Comment: I think you should use single quotes around the queryParams: {'period':'D7'}. Also there's a sample request here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getmailboxusagedetail?view=graph-rest-beta#request. Does this help?

Comment: this link has already been shared in my question. Pl read full question again, maybe you'll understand. And single quotes don't work. same error code and message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually simpler than you would think.

You just use the period parameter shown in the round brackets in the URL directly as shown in the documentation.

So, if you want to get the same report you're trying as shown in HTTP format:

```
GET /reports/getMailboxUsageDetail(period='{period_value}')
```

You will use the URL as:

```
reportsURI="https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getMailboxUsageDetail(period='D7')"


requests.get(reportsURI, headers=authHeaders)
```

This will give you a report in CSV format.
If you want in JSON format, you can use query parameters to mention format

```
formatParams = {"format":"application/json"}
requests.get(reportsURI, headers=auth, params=formatParams)
```

This will give you JSON report.